# How to solve action argument type mismatch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an action in my controller as follows.

```
    //
    // GET: /HostingAgr/Details/1
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        HostingAgreement hosting = hmEntity.HostingAgreements.SingleOrDefault(h => h.AgreementId == id);
        if (hosting == null)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Invalid Agreement ID";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(hosting);
    }
```

Now if I call URL like below.. (for testing purpose)

```
/HostingAgr/Details/1fakeid
```

System will throw an Exception.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in
>   'HostingManager.Controllers.HostingAgrController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Because the id become string in URL parameter. How can I handle this situation without throwing an error by the system?

Comment: Removed the `ActionResult` from the title since you are talking about the action and not the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept a string and try to convert it:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    var numericId;
    if (!int.TryParse(id, out numericId))
    {
        // handle invalid ids here
    }

    HostingAgreement hosting = hmEntity.HostingAgreements.SingleOrDefault(h => h.AgreementId == numericId);
    if (hosting == null)
    {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Invalid Agreement ID";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(hosting);
}
```

I would not recommend you to do so. Invalid ids should be treated as invalid ids. You are hiding errors otherwise. It might work today, but it will lead to a maintenance mess in the future.

**Update**

Anything changing `1fakeid` into `1` is a workaround. It's a bad practise doing so. You users should be forced to enter proper ids.

You can turn on `customErrors` in `web.config` to hide exception details.

If you still want to proceed I think that you can solve the problem by adding a custom `ValueProviderFactory`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I also tried this solution only. It is a workaround. But I am eager to find out the real solution that can go with "int id". Hope there might be a way to do it.

Comment: A malicious user can submit anything even if I have defined an Integer. In that case, it would be better have user friendly handler.

Comment: No. You get an error for anything but integers if you take an int as an argument.

Comment: @Muneer: You want to help your malicious users? ;) you can turn `customErrors` on to hide any exception details.

Comment: your reply can be taken as a workaround. btw, do you have any other idea of handling this situation keeping the ID as int.